# Lodash forIn can't return a loop

Tags: lodash

I loop an object using `Lodash` `forIn` and check if the existing value satisfies the condition. If the condition is true, I want to return the loop but I can't get the expected response. I printed the values of the key and it is ok but when I tried adding a condition inside the loop and when condition is `true` it skipped the `return` and continue the loop.

Code:

```
const object = {
    a: "test a",
    b: "test b",
    c: "test c",
    d: "test d"
}
 
_.forIn(object, function(value, key) {
  console.log(value);
  if (value === "test b") return
});
```

Output:

```
"test a"
"test b"
"test c"
"test d"
```

Expected output:

```
"test a"
"test b"
```

Reproduce using Runkit:
https://runkit.com/killua/lodash-forin-can-t-return-a-loop

Comment: You have to return false to exit the loop early.

Comment: thanks it's working, `return false`